# Why floats within a wrapper which is immediate child of body tag accept 100% height

Tags: html, css, css-float

Best way to explain my question would be using code samples. I have linked two fiddles.

[Immediate Child](http://jsfiddle.net/32xhwcjf/)
In this example, `.wrapper`  is a immediate child of body and the two floats `.left, .right` accept the property of `height: 100%;`

[Nested Child](http://jsfiddle.net/32xhwcjf/1/)
In this example, `.wrapper`  is not a immediate child of body and the two floats `.left, .right` **do not** accept the property of `height: 100%;`

As far as I understand, `height: 100%;` does not work on floats and techniques using absolute postions and table-cell etc. need to used. Then why do they work in the former case.

PS: Tested in latest stable Chromium and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

`height: 100%` works only if the parent element has a height which isn't `auto`.

So in your second example, what's missing is `.container { height: 100%; }` [and then it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/32xhwcjf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to size things based on the viewport you can use `height:100vh;` instead